# JQM anchor button text appears outside of button

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

This should be another simple fix that is confusing me. I'm pulling data from a database and rendering a button for each row of the database. However, the text doesn't appear inside the button! It appears underneath it!

Here's the code:

```
$('#'+category).append('<li><a href="#itemColours" data-role="button" data-icon="false" data-rel="popup" data-mini="true" id="'+thisRow.fixture+'itemColour" class="descriptions" onClick="getItemColours(\''+thisRow.fixture+'\')" />'+thisRow.colour+'</a></li>');
```

Interestingly, when the getItemColours function runs, it shows a popup of colours and when you select one it changes the button and updates the database. That bit works just fine.

```
$('#'+item+'itemColour .ui-btn-text').text(colour);
```

here's what I get: http://i1320.photobucket.com/albums/u521/dan_jones2/buttons_zps185113ce.png
The button rendered incorrectly, the button after the function call (correct) and then the button after the list is refreshed (incorrect again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this wasn't working but I got around it by changing the anchor tag for an input button and added another function to open the popup.

Answer (score 0):

This button is working just fine in my jsFiddle example. I think this is a problem in your custom css, and it is interfering with jQM button css.

What about your class **descriptions**, maybe it is causing this problem. Or maybe you have a css that interferes with

```
<span class="ui-btn-text">....
```

Probably best thing you can do is to use for example firebug addon for Firefox or Chrome ann take a look at button HTML and CSS. Specially take care for classes added to:

```
<span class="ui-btn-text">
```

I think something gave it display: block; css property and that is causing this problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving me somewhere to look but unfortunately I completely removed my stylesheet altogether and it still displays outside the box. I am completely stumped...

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that this button is well nested inside a listview, divs and a grid?...

Comment: Also, since both the text from the database AND the newly selected item are visible when you select a new colour, I can only deduce that the data retrieved from the database isn't being treated as text in the button else it would be replaced by the text added by the getItemColours function.